# Is $\phi$ a norm of E?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $(E, \| \|)$ be a normed space.

We define $\phi:E \rightarrow [0,\infty)$ as follows:

$$\phi(e)= \dfrac{\|e\|}{1+\|e\|}$$

Is $\phi$ a norm of $E$?

Please help!
Thank you!

P.S.
This question looks familiar to [Show that d_b is metric](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/310612/show-that-d-bx-y-fracdx-y1dx-y-is-a-metric),
but I think it asks different thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not a norm. If $\|x\|\ne 0$, then
$$
\varphi(2x)=\frac{\|2x\|}{1+\|2x\|}=\frac{2\|x\|}{1+2\|x\|}\ne 2\frac{\|x\|}{1+\|x\|}=2\varphi(x).
$$

Comment: thank you! In these kinds of questions we basically just take one of the norm properties and find a counterexample,right?